# Is learning how to make my own MVC in PHP a waste of time?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

I've been following a tutorial series on how to create my own MVC framework in PHP for user login, register, log out, etc. However, I'm beginning to wonder if it's necessary to learn how to make my own MVC or just use an existing one like CakePHP or the other, numerous frameworks.

I'm learning specifically to get into freelance web development. Is it necessary in modern web development? Or do most websites already use a premade framework. Thanks.

Comment: Learning how to make your own MVC isn't a waste of time, but using it for other sites probably is.  Knowing why MVC frameworks do what they do is a good way to understand how things work in other frameworks, but it'd be incredibly hard to maintain your own MVC framework when you compare the feature sets available in Cake, Laravel, Symfony, and Yii.

Comment: It's definitely no waste of time. You'll start implementing a web framework. By doing this you'll learn a lot. Then, at some point, you'll surprisingly discover, that what you actually needed to implement from the first moment were NOT a web framework, but only an application following a correct separation of concerns (e.g. a correctly applied web MVC architecture) and good programming principles, and making use of the awesome libraries/services provided by yourself, or by others on the web.

Comment: My advice: learn what MVC is, which and how components are involved, how you can structure your application correspondingly, how to implement your own libraries, and how to use external libraries/components/services as plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, it's never a waste of time if you are learning something usefull. Your thought is like "Why i have to learn maths in school if now we have computers to calculate everything...".

You can create your own MVC framework and never use it in any project, but now you know how things works behind the scenes in frameworks, and it's very usefull in any area, you can track bugs and find solutions much more faster when you have this kind of knowledge.

Not to mention the fact you can use it in small projects, where using a big framework would be a waste of resources.

Comment: I forgot to mark this question as answered. My apologies.